# User control re-size automatically at run time

Tags: vb.net, user-controls

I have a user control that has label and text box but i can't determine why they are always re-sizing during runtime. Here are the snap-shot:

[image: design time]

[image: run time]

as you can see...the objects has been resize and the spacing has been change.
I dont think that it has to do with my code...Is it only the settings of vb.net?
Please help.

Comment: Looks like your using some 3rd party GUI controls, which ones? In this siituation I usually colour controls bright Yellow, Red, Orange & etc (or use Spy++) so I can see the panel/container that is causing the unwanted resize. I think you want to use two panels, or fix one panels width in a SplitContainer.

Comment: actually I used a 3rd party GUI, and I used them to create my own control..and place them to a form..then when i run the program..my form will be treated a a control and add it to a panel and dock it..and that's the problem show...the object i created was resize.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just found the answer to my question. Instead of user control, I change the form (the container) **AutoScaleMode** from **Form** to **None**.
Thanks everyone!
Cheers!

Comment: I had this problem with a User Control within a User Control (don't ask). This fix did the trick for me.

Answer (score 4):

Please check the value of the **Anchor** property in your textboxes, labels and buttons inside the user control.
Probably is set to maintain the distance from the Right border of their container (the usercontrol)

Comment: i can see the anchor..top and left...now what will i have to do?

Comment: Another possibility is a font change executed at runtime, but from your screenshoot does not seem to be so. Do you have other control containers between on the usercontrol and the textboxes (a panel or something)?

Comment: yes i have..in my usercontrol (i called it ctxTextBox) it has split panel, label and textbox.

Comment: Sorry, tried but can't reproduce this behavior. If you are willing, you could post on pastebin the skeleton code of your usercontrol (just the interface)

Comment: i think it is ok for now that my objects move in runtime as long as it will not affect the process of the form. thanks for you time.

Comment: I wish to help you, but without the current designer code it is pratically impossible to say.

Comment: btw...i trace my code and it seems that the error fires when i place the form to a panel..you see i have a single main form (not a MDI) that has a tabpanel with tabpanel inside and has a several forms within..(i hope you understand what i am trying to say..thanks!)

Comment: To show the form and designer code you could simply code to http://www.pastebin.com and copy/paste the code of your form.cs, form.designer.cs and the same of your usercontrol. Of course remove any proprietary information that you don't want to divulge. After that publish here the link to the pastebin page.

Answer (score 4):

Try with the **AutoScaleMode** property of the user control, if is setted to **Font** change it to **None**.

In ocations the container (Could be the Form) have a font size and type diferent to the user control, and if the user control have this property set to **Font** then it will try to resize itself to cover the new font type and size.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion...i'll try it and inform you later.

Answer (score 2):

I have been able to replicate your problem. I created a user control and struggled for ages in trying to get it to re-size. Initially added a split container to my user control as you suggested you did, but it I just couldnt get it to resize.

I wondered in the dafault margin of 3,3,3,3 might have something to do with it. When I had initially added my split container it was smaller than the user control hense not being able to re-create the problem.

If my split-conainer and my user control were the same width then the margins were more obvious and it infact increased the width of my user control.

Of course your issue could be completely unrelated to this but I would suggest checking your margins compared to the widths of controls. I appreciate that the margins might be completely necessary to you but why not remove them at least if its just to check if this fixes your problem. Or by ensuring the width of your split container is less than the width of the user control after subtracting the margin from each side. E.g if your user control has a width of 300 and your split-container has margins of 3,3,3,3, then check your split container is smaller than 300-3-3 = 294.

Just a theory, may not actually be useful.... Good luck